# Single page application with multiple css files, how to divide css in files?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, single-page-application

I am creating one Angular Kendo Application.
I am planning to create a single page application.
I want to divide all the business login in multiple pages.
Different JavaScript, CSS and HTML files for each page.
I am dynamically loading these html files as per user interaction.

As per the single page architecture we need to include all the JavaScript and CSS file in the main page where we dynamically load all the pages.

So my question is, how can I divide CSS styles for each screen.
Do I need to have different class/id names for each screen?

Can I do something like below?

```
// Page1.html
<div id="myPage1">
   <div class="something">Page</div>
</div>

// Page1.css
#myPage1 .something { color: black; }


// Page2.html
<div id="myPage2">
   <div class="something">Page</div>
</div>

// Page2.css
#myPage2 .something { color: blue; }
```

So `Page1.css` and `Page2.css` will be loaded at one time in main layout.
And when I load `Page2.html` then style `Page2.css` will be applied.

Which is the correct way?

Comment: Since they are different selectors, in doesn't really matter if they would be in the same file or not. In general you would combine your css & minifiy it before deployment, so only a smaller css file has to be loaded once. During development, nothing is stopping you to load them separatly ofcourse :)

Comment: Unless you are using angular 1.5 there is no good way. (So you can use component name as id in css) I prefer using classes (class="page1"), but you can use ids to determine page. Or you can just make all element classes different like 'page1-input'. Doesnt really matter.

Answer (score -1):

You should not divide each page's css into a different file, keep it all in one file to reduce latency and add reference to the css file or files in the index.html page or whatever the main page is.

For JavaScript, each Angular Controller will have its own file, at the end you should have something to bundle all these files using either Gulp, Grunt or if you are using Visual Studio you can use Web Essentials or MVC Bundling

Comment: First, build should concat and minify css like js. Second, no one creates build which depends on IDE.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Yes, you right, and this exactly what i have said, Gulp and grunt are used to combine the css and JavaScript on file change.

and both are not related to the IDE, MVC Bundling is not related to the IDE, Only web essentials are and it is not only used for that, it has a lot for other useful features

Comment: I'm not going to downvote this because it is a good answer for some, but not for a fairly large single page app. Our app is 750 screens and we are looking to switch to single page REACT. The CSS is going to be interesting, because no one wants a 100MB CSS include. Unfortunately html5 scopes styles were deprecated.